# Device not Registered message received by server while sending notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

My device is successfully registered with GCM server and it fetches a registration key which gets stored in mysql server in my server. For few days the notification is pushed successfully to the device but after that the GCM starts giving error device not registered while pushing the notification. The user has not uninstalled the application still we are getting this message. Please help guys.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per documentation, GCM registration ID does not get expire.
Please check if application was upgraded. If yes, you need to re-register for GCM. Other than this I don't see any issue.

Comment: The application was not upgraded yet we have faced this issue. Its kind of unique issue, hence posted this issue here.

Comment: Ok. There might be some issue related to Network. Please check if network which is being used is changed. There might be some proxy in between which is blocking GCM Push. We had faced similar issue in the office network where firewall was not allowing GCM push. However, I don't think this will cause "device not registered" error.